Faltaste vs. Te Faltaron
What sounds more natural in Spanish for "You missed a lot of classes", "faltaste a muchas clases" or "te faltaron muchas clases"? Does the first option place the blame squarely on you, while the second option suggests that others are to blame? Or are there other subtleties I am missing?

The key point here is that those sentences are using different meanings of the same verb faltar. You can see those meanings checking the DLE entry
faltar

1 - intr. Dicho de una cualidad o de una circunstancia: No existir en
lo que debiera tenerla.
4 - intr. No acudir a una cita u obligación.

The difference is even more clear and with examples if we check the student edition
faltar

2 - intr. No existir alguien o algo para una persona o cosa, o no
existir en la cantidad suficiente. A la ensalada le falta el
aceite.
4 - intr. No acudir alguien a un lugar. Ayer falté a clase.
El capataz pasó lista para saber quién había faltado.

Let's use the second for clarifying your question.
In your first sentence

[ES] Faltaste a muchas clases
[EN] You missed a lot of lessons

we are using 4.
In your second sentence

[ES] Te faltaron muchas clases
[EN] You didn't get enough lessons

we are using 2. Notice that I changed how the sentence is translated.
A more "closer" passive translation sounds weird and unnatural to me: Not enough lessons were given to you
In no case there is a direct blaming, there is no person responsible for the missing lessons explicitly mentioned. We need more context in both cases to understand the reason. Did you skip the lessons voluntarily? Did you run out of money for paying driving lessons? Was the subject of the lessons too complex and the number of hours so reduced?
In my opinion there is a slight difference in saying

Faltaste a muchas clases
vs
(Te) Perdiste muchas clases

First option is closer to skip [you didn't attend with no proper reason] than the second one [you couldn't help losing those lessons]. But this difference is totally subjective. As I said, we need more context for establishing a culprit. Or we should use a more colloquial verb for reflecting that you willingly skip them.

"Faltaste a muchas clases" means "you were absent in many lessons". The person may have missed the lessons for voluntary or involuntary reasons (e.g. laziness or sickness, respectively).
"Te faltaron muchas clases" can be literally translated as "many lessons were missing for you". The idea here is that, for some reason, many lessons were not provided and, as a result, the person's knowledge or performance is poor.

Faltaste a muchas clases, ya que eso indica el sentido de la frase You missed a lot of classes que podría también traducirse como Perdiste muchas clases.
El contexto es que una persona faltó/perdió/no asistió/se voló o cualquier sinónimo que indique que no estuvo presente en muchas clases.

El detalle con "Te faltaron muchas clases" es que no es muy común usarlo en español si no hablamos de una cantidad pequeña, por ejemplo se puede usar en algunos casos como:

Te faltaron muchas clases para poder conseguir tu licencia de conducir. (You missed many classes to get your driver's license)

En este contexto, el "Te Faltaron muchas clases" indica un numero (a veces concreto) de clases de conducción para aprobar, porque se sabe que sin clases de conducción no se puede pasar una prueba para obtener la licencia de conducir, además hablamos de un numero pequeño de clases.
Si lo ponemos en el contexto de un año escolar casi nunca decimos "Te faltaron muchas clases y por eso reprobaste" (y ojo que yo respondo en base a haber nacido en América Latina y vivir en España) lo que normal mente decimos es "Faltaste a muchas clases y por eso reprobaste".
En conclusión: Te faltaron muchas clases podríamos usarlo cuando ese numero de clases es poco y contable fácilmente, por ejemplo, "Te faltaron un par de clases mas para aprobar", o también "Te faltaron dos clases para terminar el curso y obtener tu diploma".

Aclaración: Yo no soy profesor de español ni nada de eso, ni erudito de la ciencia de la gramática, yo siempre respondo (y lo pueden corroborar en mis respuestas) en base a como hablamos o que significa algo en ámbitos comunes.

Sorry if I was unclear, but I am hoping for an answer that also discusses "te faltaron muchas classes" and the differences between it and "faltaste a muchas classes," when might somone say "te faltaron" over "faltaste", or is "te faltaron" just plain wrong?

@mdrichey intenté aclarar mejor mi respuesta, espero te ayude aunque sea un poco a comprender mejor el concepto

La traducción de "You missed many classes to get your driver's license" no sona natural en inglés.  En lugar de eso diría "You missed too many classes to get your driver's license".  Pero no sé si "mucho" puede usarse como "demasiado"

Aunque yo hablo ingles, yo respondo en base al español, aun no tengo el nivel como para decir que es lo que normalmente se haría en inglés, lo siento, yo pensaba que tu querías en el contexto de Español. De verdad lamento no poder ayudarte

@mdrichey I think it was already explained very well in other answers, but in short, "te faltaron" in this context would be wrong, because you imply that such classes were not given (because there was a teachers' strike, because the school was flooded or burned down or whatever). And it seems to me that the meaning of your words is different.
